# Return value of command fire using socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets

My application connects to hardware which is basically a plotter machine which prints data based on the command. I am doing socket connection and firing some commands. In the hardware I can see command has been reached but I am not able to get return value of executed command. Below is the sample code. There is no error but at the execution on this line **String cmd = in.readLine();** it got stuck.

**Main.Java**

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintTest printTest = new PrintTest();
            printTest.print();
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Method**

```
public void print() throws IOException
{
    Socket socket = null;
    try
    {
        socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 10);
        System.out.println("isConnected :- " + socket.isConnected());

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        out.write("TC1004,1;");     
        out.flush();
        String cmd = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Recieved: " + cmd);
        }
        catch (Throwable ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (socket != null)
            {
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe it need a '\n' for a line.

Comment: if '\n' isn't reached, readLine() will keep receiving data from inpustream

Comment: @TomN : can you please write code din't get you by '\n"

Comment: @Harshil How can you not know what `\n` is when you're writing code that uses sockets?

Comment: @Kayaman : I am new to socket so I don't know much about this

Comment: @Harshil You're not just new to sockets, you have to be new to Java not to have used `\n`. It's not wise to jump directly into socket programming when you don't know the basics of the language.

Comment: @Kayaman : ok sir, I will take care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readLine();` will read (or block) until it encounters a line feed, so that's why you're getting stuck. However you didn't use a line feed in the command you sent either, which is suspicious since there must be some agreed form in the protocol to be able to tell commands apart (`flush()` is not enough).

I suspect the plotter is still waiting for you to finish your command with a `\n`before you can read anything it returns.